# register js for a defined page in script-calls.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have this `js` code

```
var shown = true;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  child.style.opacity = shown ? 0 : 1;
  shown = !shown;
});
```

The `js` is related to the following `css`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

and `html`:

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I use this code for a particular [page](http://goo.gl/3sMxu6), not for the entire site and it works just fine except the fact that on any other page ([Home](http://goo.gl/qxwdVH), etc) I receive an error telling me that the `.parent` element is missing. Nothing unusual as long as I don't need it in that page at all.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(anonymous function) @ shomz.js:6
```

If this helps, in this moment, the `js` code defined as `shomz.js` is registered like this:

```
...
// Main Scripts
function register_js() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url_prefix = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';
        // Register 
        wp_register_script('shomz', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/shomz.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);

        // Enqueue
        wp_enqueue_script('shomz');
        wp_localize_script( 'app', 'themeajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
...
```

At this point, in order to avoid defining `.parent/.child` elements for every single page, I was wondering, is there any possibility to register the `js` in the `script-calls.php` file, being active only for a defined page(s) by id for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your script enqueueing function call with an if condition checking whether the current page's id matches the id of the side on which you want the script to be enqueued or not.

```
// Main Scripts
function register_js() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url_prefix = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';

        /* Get id of current page*/
        $page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
        /* Compare the desired page's id with the current page's id, if       they match, enqueue shomz*/
        if(YOUR_ID == $page_id){
            wp_register_script('shomz', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/shomz.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('shomz');
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'app', 'themeajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your feed-back, I've received the White Screen of Death .I'll expose the whole `//Main Scripts` section above in a few, maybe there is something that is missing.

Comment: Make sure to set wordpress debug mode to true

Comment: It looks like the way the page id it's defined, produce the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/notio-wp/inc/script-calls.php on line 43 `  I've defined `if(<2465> == $page_id){` is it wrong?

Comment: Yes please dont use <> it was meant as a placeholder, sorry for not being clear

Comment: You should See the file in which the error occurs in chromes console as well

Comment: It's ok, maybe I should know that already :P almost there, I still receive an error in the Chrome console no matter what page I am visiting, this time  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` The error looks the same on every page but it's petty hard to tell from my point of view, In home page for example, the line it's located in the index `<script type="text/javascript"><br />` anyway one thing is for sure, It's not in JS file, hope this helps?

Comment: I suggest you to open a New question regarding that New Problem and Mark the current one as correct

Comment: The error is gone as soon as I switch the `debug mode` back to `false` and it looks like it was there before I start to use this code modification, I've verified that.Sounds fair, I really appreciate it!!! Vielen Dank

Comment: I understand that this code can be used only for a specific page defined by `ID`. Is there any possibility to tweak it in order to be used [for more than one pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139641/register-js-for-more-than-one-predefined-by-id-pages-in-script-calls-php)?