# register js for more than one predefined by id pages in script-calls.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have this `js` code (saved as `shomz.js` file)

```
var shown = true;
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var child = document.querySelector('.child');

parent.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  child.style.opacity = shown ? 0 : 1;
  shown = !shown;
});
```

The `js` is related to the following `css`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}


p {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

and `html`:

```
<div class="parent">
<img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />

<div class="child">
<img src="http://maui.hawaii.edu/tlc/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2013/11/testing.jpg" alt="" width="500px" height="auto" />
```

Starting from the below `js` register procedure (made by [Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062455/register-js-for-a-defined-page-in-script-calls-php/30062649#30062649)) in `script-calls.php` for a single page by `ID`, I was wondering what is the best way to tweak the code, in order to define more than one page (2,3,N) also by `ID`, applying the above `shomz.js` code. I am not interested to find a global rule that will affect the whole site pages, but only the defined by `ID` pages;

```
// Main Scripts
function register_js() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url_prefix = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';

        /* Get id of current page*/
        $page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
        /* Compare the desired page's id with the current page's id, if       they match, enqueue shomz*/
        if(YOUR_ID == $page_id){
            wp_register_script('shomz', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/shomz.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('shomz');
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'app', 'themeajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array holding your specific ID's. In the if statement you'll just check if your current ID is in your defined array.

```
// Main Scripts
function register_js() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        $url_prefix = is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:';

        /* Get id of current page*/
        $page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
        /* Compare the desired page's id with the current page's id, if       they match, enqueue shomz*/
        $ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
        if (in_array($page_id, $ids)){
            wp_register_script('shomz', THB_THEME_ROOT . '/assets/js/plugins/shomz.js', 'jquery', null, TRUE);
            wp_enqueue_script('shomz');
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'app', 'themeajax', array( 'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
    }
}
```

PHP Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Vielen Dank Robin, Im sure that this will work but I have to read first to figure out how :) I'm not lazy, just noob in php stuff.

Comment: absolutely no problem ;)

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is similar with the first example from the `in-array` documentation.In this case let's say that I have 3 id's `2465`, `2466` and `2480`.I'll have to replace the `1`, `2` , `3` numbers with my id's and ... `$page_id` again with each `Id` one by one stacked one line over another? I know that sounds silly I'm just trying to figure out.Could you be so kind and please put my `ID`'s in your example ?

Comment: `$ids = array(2465,2466,2480);` , leave the `page_id`  as it is, as you'd like to compare the id of the current page and the ids defined in the $ids array.

Comment: u're very kind. works like a charm.I really appreciate it !!! mit freundlichem gruß :)